# How can I convert unsigned char to unsigned short using sse

Tags: c++, sse

I am just a beginner of sse, the question is that how to convert unsigned char array to unsigned short array by using sse

Answer (score 4):

The function you're looking for is [`_mm_cvtepu8_epi16`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_cvtepu8_epi16&expand=1546).

Comment: but after the operation of _mm_cvtepu8_epi16, is the result short or unsigned short

Comment: @shengfengqiao How would that matter? Any unsigned char has the same representation as either a signed or unsigned short.

Comment: @Sneftel Thanks a lot, is there any load function for me to load unsigned char data  to the m128i register, or the only way is set function

Comment: @shengfengqiao Yes, there is, and you should be able to find it easily by searching the intel intrinsics guide.